# Is there a way to prevent object mode change?

Tags: python

Once setting an object mode with `bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')`, can it be programmatically "locked" in that mode until the script explicitly sets another mode? Effectively locking out this button [image] or any other ways of changing modes.

I've tried forcing it back using a modal operator if it detects a different mode, but that seems clunky and I feel like there should be a better way?

```
if bpy.context.object.mode != 'EDIT':
   bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or... You could register an operator named `object.mode_set` that does nothing and unregister it afterwards:

```
import bpy
from bpy.props import (
    BoolProperty, 
    StringProperty,
)

class FakeModeSet(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Locked Object Mode"""
    bl_idname = "object.mode_set"
    bl_label = "Fake Mode Set Operator to lock all the mode setting"
    mode: StringProperty() # So it doesn't get angry when buttons from UI 
    toggle: BoolProperty() # try to pass stuff to it
    
    def execute(self, context):
        return {'FINISHED'}


bpy.utils.register_class(FakeModeSet)
#bpy.utils.unregister_class(FakeModeSet)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Still don't really understand how it works though. Does it simply override the inbuilt `object.mode_set` operator?

Comment: Apparently. I just tried it and it works. I do not fully understand how the default one works after unregistering it, but it does. I guess the operator is not written in Python that's why. This wouldn't work with panels or headers or other stuff. If you for example register a new header for 3d view simply unregistering leaves it broken and the original Python code making the UI needs to be run to restore it.

Answer (score 2):

##### Lock Edit Mode for 10 seconds

```
import bpy

def msgbus_callback():
    print("mode changed")
    try:
        if bpy.context.object.mode != 'EDIT':
            bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
    except:
        pass

owner = "owner"

bpy.msgbus.subscribe_rna(
    key=(bpy.types.Object, 'mode'),
    owner=owner,
    args=(),
    notify=msgbus_callback
)

def in_10_sec():
    print("done")
    bpy.msgbus.clear_by_owner(owner)

bpy.app.timers.register(in_10_sec, first_interval=10)
```

##### Method 2: Use operator to block/allow some operator

Here is a operator to block `object.mode_set` and `wm.search_menu`

```
import bpy

def is_inside_viewport(event, context, header):
    r = context.region
    cy = r.height // 2 + r.y
    x = event.mouse_region_x
    y = event.mouse_region_y
    L = 0
    R = r.width
    B = 0
    T = r.height

    if header.y > cy: # header is on top
        T -= header.height
    else: # header is on bottom
        B += header.height

    if x < L: return False
    if x > R: return False
    if y < B: return False
    if y > T: return False
    return True

class MY_OP(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "view3d.my_operator"
    bl_label = "Operator"

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        header = None
        for r in context.area.regions:
            if r.type == 'TOOL_HEADER':
                tool_header = r
            elif r.type == 'HEADER':
                header = r

        if header is None:
            print("header not find, cancelled")
            return {'CANCELLED'}

        self.header = header
        self.tool_header = tool_header
        context.window_manager.modal_handler_add(self)
        return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}

    def modal(self, context, event):
        if event.type == 'ESC':
            print("operator finished")
            return {'FINISHED'}

        # check is the mouse under the viewport and not in header, but you can't use the header button
        if is_inside_viewport(event, context, self.header):
            is_mode_set = False
            for kc in context.window_manager.keyconfigs:
                for km in kc.keymaps:
                    found_keymap = km.keymap_items.match_event(event)
                    if found_keymap is not None:
                        name = found_keymap.idname
                        # print(name)
                        if name in {'object.mode_set', 'wm.search_menu'}:
                            is_mode_set = True
                            break

            if not is_mode_set:
                return {'PASS_THROUGH'}

        return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(MY_OP)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(MY_OP)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @X Y, this basically uses the same method I'm already using, (`if not "EDIT' then 'EDIT`) I was hoping there was a way to "lock the mode" using some other means? +1 though because you taught me about bpy.msgbus :)

Comment: How about running a modal operator? User cannot change the mode until the operator finish. You also can allow special operation like rotate the viewport in the operator.