# Python API - access operator's class for builtin operators

Tags: python, operator

Is it possible to access operator's class for builtin operators?

For addons, I can either import them from addon's module `from node_wrangler.operators import NWLazyMix` or from `bpy.types` -> `bpy.types.NODE_OT_nw_lazy_mix`.

I wanted to use operator's class to override `.execute` or `modal` to have a general solution to solve issues like [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/306076/python-api-run-commands-before-after-execute-of-the-operator-with-file-sele/306080) and [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/143088/subscribe-to-finished-event-of-modal-operator-and-get-result-of-the-operator/199788#199788).

Answer (score 2):

No Idea, how to access the class, but if the operator is written in Python, you can find its code. There is a bunch of operators in Blender's installation folder(on Windows they are at `C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 4.0\4.0\scripts\startup\bl_operators`) So you can just copy the code defining the operator, change it and register it again. This works as we see from the tooltip that I changed for Select Camera operator:

[image]

If the operator is not written in Python, it seems it's no longer possible to override it this way in recent versions:

[image]

That's what happens if I try to register an operator with mesh.primitive_cube_add bl_idname.

It used to be possible in previous versions and [was useful in some cases](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/273876/60759). You can still write a new operator entirely and change the UI and keymap to replace some operator, but that's a lot of work.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately it seems only pure python operators classes are accessible, not the C-defined operators.